# how to filter only by the ids from column a that have all the values ​in column b

Tags: sql, presto

Could I kindly ask for some guidance on how I can filter in Presto SQL only by the values (from column a) that have all values in column b?

So, I am looking to get all the product_ids by date that have all promotion days (from 1 - 9) in promotion_running_days column.

I tried to use 'promotion_running_days in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) but it returns also the product_ids have only 2 or 3 promotion days.

Using this query approach:

```
SELECT
    product_id
    ,date
    ,ROUND(MAX(DATE_DIFF('day', CAST(DATE_PARSE(promotion_start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS DATE), CAST(DATE_PARSE(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE))),0) AS promotion_running_days
    ,SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue    
FROM product_db 
 WHERE
        date  between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-07' 
        AND promotion_start_date>='2019-01-01' 
Group by 1,2;
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
Product Id  |Date|       |Promotion Running Days|

1          |2019-01-01|    |1|
1          |2019-01-02|    |2|
1          |2019-01-03|    |3|
1          |2019-01-04|    |4|
1          |2019-01-05|    |5|
1          |2019-01-06|    |6|
1          |2019-01-07|    |7|
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to get all the product_ids by date that have all promotion days

You seem to want aggregation.  Assuming you have at most one row per date:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue    
FROM product_db 
WHERE date  between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-07' and
      promotion_start_date>='2019-01-01' 
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 7;  -- 7 == all days
```

However, your sample results suggest `row_number()`:

```
select product_id, date,
       row_number() over (partition by product_id order by date)
from product_db
order by product_id, date;
```